# Which are the core libraries in Ubuntu?

Tags: libraries

What are core libraries in Ubuntu? I mean libraries where the APIs and ABIs are preserved across major releases, like 12.04 LTS, 14.04 LTS and 16.06 LTS. What is the **core** of Ubuntu and what is the policy on how many releases API and ABI are kept stable?

Here is [example documentation from Red Hat](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Developer_Guide/lib.compatibility.core.html), I didn't find yet equivalent documentation for Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu is a distribution based on Debian. By being a distro (distribution), it stands as a re-packaged version of the linux-kernel with lots of stuff on top (such as gnome). Since Ubuntu is branched from the last stable version of Debian, most of the core-utils that you want are actually same as those used in Debian.

I took a look at [ubuntu packages](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libc) and a search for `libc` reveals the versions used in each ubuntu version.

The core of ubuntu is the Linux Kernel, and the Ubuntu Policy on keeping releases stable is available [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/StableReleaseUpdates).

When you develop for ubuntu, you can link your package against any version of the standard libraries using the deb packaging system that Ubuntu inherits from Debian. This allows you to specify a minimum version of the library that your package needs, for instance. You do not have to worry about compatibility issues across releases, rather check for the last version of the library that supported the features you are using. The [Debian Developer Reference](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/developers-reference/) goes on details about this.

Comment: I could not find mention of keeping ABI or API stable over releases, I mean if I develop software for Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, I don't know what libraries are still stable in 16.04 LTS. This means that software may be broke next upgrade.

Comment: I found this site: http://developer.ubuntu.com/ I assume that it says all recommended development tools and practises like Red Hat documentation but it didn't help to tell how to write application that doesn't broke after platform upgrades. What are those "standard libraries" in Ubuntu you mentioned and what is the policy to keep them stable? What libaries are kept stable several releases and what are stable only in one release lifespan?